# Rust - How to add data to a triply nested HashMap

Tags: collections, rust, hashmap

I am trying to split up a bunch (50+) of json files, and to do so I want to classify their values by frequency depending on elements of the file name. Not only am I doing this but I am doing it as somewhat of a Rust newbie, because it wasn't fun enough to do in Python, for instance.

For the sake of the explanation, let's imagine files like these:

```
a-b-c-d.json
{
    "var":"foo",
    "array": [
        'one',
        'two'
    ]
}
b-c-d-f.json
{
    "var":"bar",
    "array": [
        'one',
        'three'
    ]
}
```

The data structure I want to end up with, after processing those two files, is something like this (note that this might very well be my first mistake):

```
{
  'a' : {
    'var' : { 
      'foo': 1
    }, 'array' : {
      'one': 1, 'two': 1 
    }
  },
  'b' : {
    'var' : { 
      'foo': 1,
      'bar': 1
    }, 'array' : {
      'one': 2, 'two': 1, 'three': 1
    }
  }
(also 'c', 'd' and 'f') - I hope the intention is clear with this small example
}
```

My pseudocode is more or less like this:

1. for each json file
2. split the name in parts, by '-'
3. for each element (key:value) in the json file
4. add it to result[part][key][value] as the number of occurrences

So, the type of the result variable would be `HashMap<String, HashMap<String, HashMap<String, i8>>>`

And the (actual) code in which I am getting errors is:

```
type ComponentValueElement = HashMap<String, i8>;
type ComponentElement = HashMap<String, ComponentValueElement>;
type ComponentMap = HashMap<String, ComponentElement>;
(...)
fn increase_ocurrence_of_element_in_configuration(component: &String, element: &String, value: &String, final_component_map: &mut ComponentMap) {
    final_component_map.entry(component.into()).or_insert( HashMap::new() );
    final_component_map[component].entry(element.into()).or_insert(HashMap::new());
    final_component_map[component][element].entry(value.into()).or_insert(0);

    final_component_map[component][element][value] += 1;
}
```

The errors are:

`<final_component_map[component]>.entry(element.into()).or_insert(HashMap::new());`

```
cannot borrow data in an index of `std::collections::HashMap<std::string::String, std::collections::HashMap<std::string::String, std::collections::HashMap<std::string::String, i8>>>` as mutable

cannot borrow as mutable

help: trait `IndexMut` is required to modify indexed content, but it is not implemented for `std::collections::HashMap<std::string::String, std::collections::HashMap<std::string::String, std::collections::HashMap<std::string::String, i8>>>`
```

`<final_component_map[component][element]>.entry(value.into()).or_insert(0);`

```
cannot borrow data in an index of `std::collections::HashMap<std::string::String, std::collections::HashMap<std::string::String, i8>>` as mutable

cannot borrow as mutable

help: trait `IndexMut` is required to modify indexed content, but it is not implemented for `std::collections::HashMap<std::string::String, std::collections::HashMap<std::string::String, i8>>`
```

`<final_component_map[component][element][value]> += 1;`

```
cannot assign to data in an index of `std::collections::HashMap<std::string::String, i8>`

cannot assign

help: trait `IndexMut` is required to modify indexed content, but it is not implemented for `std::collections::HashMap<std::string::String, i8>`
```

I would have thought that writing to Maps would be easier in Rust :D What exactly do I need to do to have my beautiful nested HashMap filled with the values?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It will likely be a lot more efficient to use a single hashmap, of type `HashMap<(String, String, String), i8>`.

Comment: Is... is that a thing? :D How would I add things to it? Would the entry interface work the same? Another issue could be the initialization of the map in the first place, since I iterate over all the json files, splitting and creating the first layer of the HashMap (also via `.entry().or_insert()` )

Comment: Whether something like that will work depends on what kind of access patterns you want to support. For instance, if you want to iterate over all `map[a]` you may want to use nested maps.

Comment: Yes there are different pros and cons. Using the flat structure, it will be slower to remove an entire branch, for example.

Comment: I don't really need to iterate on this for now, I just want a report of sorts so I can split the files. For that, at least in my head, the initial setup works better. But knowing that you can do HashMaps with tuples - which I didn't think of before - is valuable in itself. Thanks @PeterHall !

Comment: *Is... is that a thing?* - if it works in Python, why wouldn't it work in Rust? :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Part of the point of the `Entry` API is so that you can mutate the entry without having to look it up again. You can chain these lookups together like so:

```
fn increase_ocurrence_of_element_in_configuration(
    component: &str,
    element: &str,
    value: &str,
    final_component_map: &mut ComponentMap,
) {
    *final_component_map
        .entry(component.into())
        .or_default()
        .entry(element.into())
        .or_default()
        .entry(value.into())
        .or_default() += 1;
}
```

Comment: This is like a TV commercial for the `entry()` API. :) And you can make it even shorter using `or_default()` instead of `or_insert(HashMap::new())`. (Possibly also faster because `or_default()` is equivalent to `or_insert_with(|| HashMap::default())`, so it only calls `HashMap::new()` when the entry is vacant. OTOH `or_insert(HashMap::new())` always creates the empty hashmap and relies on the optimizer to optimize away the creation, which may or may not happen depending on the optimizer.)

Comment: @user4815162342 Updated. That's much better.

Comment: Thank you both, this has indeed solved the problem!!